# setting TableDestination while inserting pivot table through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to insert a pivot table through VBA but get some issues with setting `TableDestination`.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Src_Tbl, Version:=6). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(PvtTbl_row_loc, PvtTbl_column_loc).Address(, , xlR1C1), TableName:="Summary", DefaultVersion:=6
```

I also tried this to debug:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Src_Tbl, Version:=6). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="'" & ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name & "'!R4C10"
```

But I am getting

> Expression not defined in context

Sub routine is called from a module which sets other variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what finally worked. Many thanks to @Cyrill for his guidence-

```
Sub AddPvtTbl_Chart(Src_Tbl As ListObject, PvtTbl_row_loc, PvtTbl_column_loc As Integer)

    Dim destloc, cell_in_RC As String
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    cell_in_RC = "R" & "" & PvtTbl_row_loc & "" & "C" & "" & PvtTbl_column_loc & ""
    destloc = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & cell_in_RC & ""

    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Src_Tbl.Range)
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=destloc, TableName:="Summary")
```

Comment: Note that `Dim destloc` is defined as Variant, not as a string (not sure if you were aware).  If you want both items to be strings, you would want to write: `Dim destloc as String, cell_in_RC As String`

Comment: As you already have the ListObject: Why don't you just use it directly as SourceData? As you already have the row and column, why don't you just use `ActiveSheet.Cells(PvtTbl_row_loc, PvtTbl_column_loc)` as TableDestination? (In other words: I suggest to read my answer again :) )

Answer (score 0):

You have to `set` a pivot cache and table, such that:

```
'Define Pivot Cache
Src_Tbl = "Sheet1!A1:B200" 'STRING
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Src_Tbl) 'removed ", Version:=6" for the sake of creating.  can add in if needed

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
destloc = "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!R4C10" 'STRING
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=destloc, TableName:="Report")
```

You may need to ensure that you're recognizing R1C1 notation with the destination location, ensuring the strings for source and destination are appropriate (can't be a range within VBA, e.g. `range(cells(),cells())`).

---

**Edit1:**

Showing the change from comments below this answer:

```
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Src_Tbl.Range)
```

The suggestion was to display as a `String` (my post) but was able to work around with the existing `ListObject` by using `.Range`

Comment: Its not working @Cyril. For actual source data I am passing a Table. I am adding multiple sheet and in each sheet there is a table and from that table I am deriving a pivotable. The moment my pivot table subroutine execute "Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=UC_table_name)" statement, it exits. Not able to find out the root cause, UC_Table_name is a string assigned with name of the master table in the worksheet.

Comment: @Sanjeev To ask the question, you don't have an `On Error Resume Next` in your subroutine, right?  If you are changing your `Src_Tbl` per sheet, e.g., change the activesheet name reference in support of the common named range, that should be sufficient to capture all of your different tables.

Comment: I did some more experimentation. I made following change in your code SourceData:=Src_Tbl->SourceData:=Src_Tbl.Range, and it worked :) Also I am not setting Src_Tbl as string instead it the ListObject. Thank for your direction its working.

Comment: @Sanjeev Glad that helped you get to what you needed!  If you would either mark this as an answer or post your updated code as an answer so this can be marked as completed, that would be appreciated!  Helps people with both searching and others who are trying to answer questions figure where to spend our time!

Comment: @Sanjeev I updated my post to indicate what I believe you wrote in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

To derive a `PivotTable` from a "table" (=`ListObject`) on each worksheet, you may use the `ListObject` itself as source data for the `PivotCache`:

```
Private Sub PivotTablesBasedOnListobjects()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
            Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
            Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                SourceData:=lo)
            Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable( _
                TableDestination:=ws.Cells(4, 10))
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

The destination for the pivottable must not overlap the `ListObject.Range`, so you may compare its dimensions to define your "PvtTbl_row_loc" and "PvtTbl_column_loc".